# Insert new key value in multidimensional array at specific location

Tags: php, arrays

`[Rubik] => Array([font-style] => Array([0] => 400))`

this is my existing array and i want to add new key value `[1]=>900`
after `[0]=> 400`

Thanks!!

Comment: so what you've tried?

Comment: Try `$a["Rubik"]["font-style"][] = 900;`

Comment: 'array_splice($existing_array,2, 0, array(array('1' => '900')));' i have try this but this function is not insert new key value at specific location.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try with below code

```
$array = array();
$array['Rubik']['font-style'][0] = 400;
$array['Rubik']['font-style'][1] = 900;
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple different ways, depending on how the rest of your code looks you can use anything.

```
$array = [
    'Rubik' => [
        'font-style' => [
            400
        ]
    ]
];
```

You can simply add it

```
$array['Rubik']['font-style'][] = 900;
// or
$array['Rubik']['font-style'][1] = 900;
```

To insert a value at a specific location an array you can use array splice.

```
array_splice($array['Rubik']['font-style'], 1, 0, 900);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a value 400 at the first position which has index 0. If you add 900 to that array the next index will be 1.

Your code could look like:

```
$array["Rubik"]["font-style"][] = 900;
```